# Run weblogic in jdeveloper java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind

Tags: java, weblogic, jdeveloper

I have a project
When i run project with IntegratedWeblogicServer. It is problem as below

```
<Aug 10, 2016 2:46:54 PM ICT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN> 
<Aug 10, 2016 2:46:54 PM ICT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING> 
<Aug 10, 2016 2:46:54 PM ICT> <Emergency> <Security> <BEA-090087> <Server failed to bind to the configured Admin port. The port may already be used by another process.> 
    <Aug 10, 2016 2:46:54 PM ICT> <Error> <Server> <BEA-002606> <Unable to create a server socket for listening on channel "Default". The address 10.72.4.73 might be incorrect or another process is using port 7101: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind.> 
    <Aug 10, 2016 2:46:54 PM ICT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason: Server failed to bind to any usable port. See preceeding log message for details.> 
    <Aug 10, 2016 2:46:54 PM ICT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED> 
    <Aug 10, 2016 2:46:54 PM ICT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down> 
    <Aug 10, 2016 2:46:54 PM ICT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN>
```

Who know and resoled this problem ? 
Please help me ! Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if the port 7101 is already opened on the server corresponding to the ip address 10.72.4.73?

Comment: i have checked port 7101 but no have using this port

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are pretty misleading, not to say downright incompetent, but `Cannot assign requested address` means you have specified a non-local IP address. If it was a port already in use problem it would be `address already in use`.

```
The address 10.72.4.73 might be incorrect
```

This is the only part of the log that is relevant.